# SQL query returning values based on values in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to write a query that returns a value from a different row in the same table based on a value in a row and have it return that value on the same row?

I have a table with columns `SC_CODE`, `SC_DESC`, `SC_ALT_CODE`, and `SC_CANX_CODE`:

- `SC_CODE` values are `1`, `2`, `901`, `902`, etc.
- `SC_DESC` values are `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Test4`, etc.
- `SC_ALT_CODE` values are `NULL`, `3`, `4`, `NULL`, etc.
- `SC_CANX_CODE` values are `901`, `902`, `903`, `904`, etc.

My query needs to return something like:

```
1, Test1, NULL, 901, Test3
2, Test2, 3, 902, Test4
```

Here, `Test3` is the `SC_DESC` of `SC_CODE 901` and `Test4` is the `SC_DESC` of `SC_CODE 902`, etc.

Comment: Clarification is needed

Comment: Haha your question is terrible but makes me laugh.  Can you add an example of what you mean and tag your database?

Comment: Does that help? @AaronDietz

Comment: What dbms do you use?

Comment: MSSMS @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
DECLARE @TEST AS TABLE
(
        SC_CODE INT
    ,   SC_DESC VARCHAR(255)
    ,   SC_ALT_CODE INT
    ,   SC_CANX_CODE INT 
)

INSERT @TEST (SC_CODE, SC_DESC, SC_ALT_CODE, SC_CANX_CODE)
VALUES (1, 'Test1', NULL, 901)
,       (2, 'Test2', 3, 902)
,       (901, 'Test3', 4, 903)
,       (902, 'Test4', NULL, 904)
,       (3, 'Test5', NULL, NULL)

SELECT  T.SC_CODE
,       T.SC_DESC
,       T.SC_ALT_CODE
,       T.SC_CANX_CODE
,       T2.SC_DESC AS CANX_DESC
,       T3.SC_DESC AS ALT_DESC
FROM    @TEST AS T
JOIN    @TEST AS T2
    ON  T2.SC_CODE = T.SC_CANX_CODE
LEFT JOIN   @TEST AS T3
    ON  T3.SC_CODE = T.SC_ALT_CODE
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| SC_CODE | SC_DESC | SC_ALT_CODE | SC_CANX_CODE | CANX_DESC | ALT_DESC |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | Test1   | NULL        |          901 | Test3     | NULL     |
|       2 | Test2   | 3           |          902 | Test4     | Test5    |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Edit**
Added a join for SC_ALT_CODE as asked in comment. Note I added a row to the sample data to get result. Also note the use of `LEFT JOIN`, not every record has an Alternative. With `LEFT JOIN` you don't loose those records.

Comment: I'm still playing with your example, and THANK YOU!!!  To add a wrinkle, what if I need to do the same thing for SC_ALT_CODE as well as the SC_CANX_CODE?

Comment: In that case do the same again, add another join on `T3.SC_CODE = T.SC_ALT_CODE` (or something to that effect)

Comment: @Levi I've updated my answer to illustrate your comment.

Comment: I have it working but it is not including any SC_ALT_CODE or SC_CANX_CODE that is NULL.  I have 89 rows in the table and only 21 are being shown???  I am assuming its because on the JOIN, if it has a NULL, there is nothing to equate but could be wrong. @HoneyBadger

Comment: If you want those records too, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead on `JOIN`

Comment: BINGO!!!  You're the best, and glad I could give y'all of comic relief!  Thanks again HoneyBadger!!!

Comment: @Levi... The best way to say thank you is to accept and upvote the answer. Another good way is to write a better question next time ;). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Its still not entirely clear what you are trying to do but I think you are looking for the LEAD function with an offset of 2, to produce the desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbltmp(
SC_CODE int,
SC_DESC varchar(5),
SC_ALT_CODE int,
SC_CANX_CODE int);

INSERT INTO #tbltmp values 
(1,'Test1',NULL,901),
(2,'Test2',3,902),
(901,'Test3',4,903),
(902,'Test4',NULL,904);

SELECT
SC_CODE,
SC_DESC,
SC_ALT_CODE,
SC_CANX_CODE,
LEAD(SC_DESC,2) OVER (ORDER BY SC_DESC) SC_DESC
FROM #tbltmp

DROP TABLE #tbltmp
```